# NoClassDefFoundError: scala/collection/Seq

Tags: java, reflection, jruby

I'm calling a method in a Java class from JRuby via reflection

```
fact = Factory.factory('aString')
```

calls this method in java

```
public static Service factory(String url) throws IllegalArgumentException { return new _Service(url); };
```

and I'm getting

```
Java::JavaLang::NoClassDefFoundError: scala/collection/Seq
```

Comment: it might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14417814/why-do-i-get-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-when-i-trying-to-run-this-code

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It happened because my java code was build with Scala, but at runtime scala library wasn't available. Added scala-library.jar to classpath, that resolved it.